# Weirdness with around aspect in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I am new to ruby

Trying to write an around aspect. My code is as follows

My code looks as follows

```
module Utils
  module Aspects

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(self)
    end

    def around_aspect(method_name, before_proc, after_proc)

      code = %Q[
        def #{method_name} *args, &block
          #{before_proc.call}
          old_#{method_name} *args, &block
          #{after_proc.call}
        end
      ]

      class_eval %Q[
        alias_method :old_#{method_name}, :#{method_name}
      ]

      class_eval code
    end

    # def before_aspect method_name, before_proc
    #   around_aspect method_name, before_proc, ->(){}
    # end
    #
    # def after_aspect method_name, after_proc
    #   around_aspect method_name, ->(){}, after_proc
    # end
  end
end


class Test
  include Utils::Aspects

  def test
    puts 'test'
  end

  before = ->(){puts 'before'}
  after = ->(){puts 'after'}
  around_aspect :test,before,after
end

Test.new.test
```

The problem is that when i do `Test.new.test` I expect it to print
before, test and after" in order. But right now it prints "before,after and test"

Comment: You can avoid `eval` entirely here if you convert that to `define_method` with the relevant `send` or `call` calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that when i do `Test.new.test` I expect it to print
>   before, test and after" in order. But right now it prints "before,after and test"

No, it doesn't. When calling `Test.new.test` it only prints `test`. `before` and `after` are printed when defining the wrapped method, i.e. when calling `around_advice`.

Try to put a `puts` in between the call to `around_advice` and the call to `Test.new.test` (and try to call `test` several times) to observe this:

```
puts '______________________'

Test.new.test
Test.new.test

# before
# after
# ______________________
# test
# test
```

You are calling the lambdas only once, when defining the method:

```
  code = %Q[
    def #{method_name} *args, &block
      #{before_proc.call}
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      old_#{method_name} *args, &block
      #{after_proc.call}
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    end
  ]
```

You need to call them every time when calling the method:

```
  code = %Q[
    def #{method_name} *args, &block
      before_proc.call
      old_#{method_name} *args, &block
      after_proc.call
    end
  ]
```

However, it would be much easier to just use `Module#prepend`, after all, that's what it's there for:

```
module Aspects
  refine Module do
    def around_aspect(method_name, before_proc, after_proc)
      prepend(Module.new do
        define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
          before_proc.()
          super(*args, &block)
          after_proc.()
        end
      end)
    end
  end
end

class Test
  using Aspects

  def test
    puts 'test'
  end

  before = -> {puts 'before'}
  after = -> {puts 'after'}
  around_aspect :test, before, after
end
```

Comment: Why would you `refine Module` instead of prepending `Module.new { def around_aspect ... end }` directly to the `Test.singleton_class`?!

Comment: Not sure the `proc.()` calling notation is very conventional here. Also keep in mind that the return value of this wrapped function is now broken, the result of the call to `super` needs to be captured and returned.

Comment: @tadman: that matches the OP's behavior. An around advice is supposed to be able to change the return value. However, in the OP's code, there is no way for the after block to inspect the return value, so there's not much it can do.

Comment: @JörgWMittag you are right, the calls to before and after are getting evaluated at define time rather than call time in my code but I don't know why. I am evaluating the expressions #{before_proc.call} in my method definition and since I am using class_eval that method is being part of the current class so shouldn't it be executed when i call the method on an instance of the class. Not sure what is going on

Comment: @AbdulRahman: You are interpolating the expression `#{before_proc.call}` into the string of code. String interpolation happens when the string is parsed. And it only happens once. The result of that interpolation is simply `nil` which gets converted using `to_s` (string interpolation always uses `to_s` when the object being interpolated is not already a string). `nil.to_s` is simply the empty string, so there is no trace left of the advice in the generated code, and the only thing observable is the side effect (`puts`) at the time you interpolate the string.

Answer (score 0):

Just putting my code up here. This is how i ended up achieving what i was trying to do, module.prepend as suggested above is another way

```
module Utils
  module Aspects

    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(self)
    end

    def around_aspect(method_name, before_proc, after_proc)

      new_method_name = Random.new_seed.to_s

      alias_method :"#{new_method_name}", :"#{method_name}"

      define_method "#{method_name}" do |*args, &block|
        before_proc.call
        send(:"#{new_method_name}", *args, &block)
        after_proc.call
      end
    end

    def before_aspect method_name, before_proc
      around_aspect method_name, before_proc, ->(){}
    end

    def after_aspect method_name, after_proc
      around_aspect method_name, ->(){}, after_proc
    end
  end
end


class Test
  include Utils::Aspects

  def test

    puts 'test'
  end

  before = ->(){puts 'before'}
  after = ->(){puts 'after'}

  before_aspect :test, before
  after_aspect :test, after
end


Test.new.test
```